# Dynamic Gallery: Worpress' equivalents for Wix's collection and repeater

Tags: database, gallery

I am recently trying WordPress (the WordPress.com one instead of WordPress.org) to create a webpage that displays a list of events that the website visitors can participate in. I have been using Wix for a similar project in the past, and what I did was: creating a database of the events using Wix's *collection* and displaying the data (thumbnail, event name, event date, etc.) on the webpage using *repeater*. I wonder if WordPress has any equivalents for these two Wix features.

I was thinking of creating the event database using MySQL, but apparently MySQL is only available for WordPress.org and not WordPress.com. I did some Google search and it looks like I need to use some plugins such as WooCommerce and wpDataTables to make the dynamic gallery.

This is my first post in this forum. I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you, everyone!

Comment: For help with WordPress.com you should contact them for support. This site is regarding custom development with the WordPress.org software.

Comment: take a look at custom post types, but keep in mind that wordpress.com is a paid 3rd party service by Automattic, this stack is for developers asking programming questions about the open source WordPress available at wordpress.org

Comment: @JacobPeattie Ah I see! Thanks very much for the information!

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you very much for your explanation! I took a look at Custom Post Types, and found out that it's just what I need. And I have decided to use WordPress.org for this project :-)